# Connect to Oracle Cloud Database from Google Apps Script

Tags: oracle, google-apps-script, jdbc

I'd like to use Google Apps Script to connect directly to an Oracle Cloud database.  It appears that Google Apps Script supports making a JDBC connection to Oracle from my reading at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc where it says

> The JDBC service supports Google Cloud SQL MySQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL
> Server, and Oracle databases.

The trick seems to be in getting the right value for the "url" property for the "getConnection" method as described at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getconnectionurl

In the Oracle Cloud Database docs, I found a page that talks connecting with JDBC at https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/connect-jdbc-thin-tls.html#GUID-9C4FBA97-C486-42E9-883F-13B9EB1DB160 which gives an example of how to build the DB_URL for making the JDBC connection as follows:

```
DB_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@my_connect_string
```

and shows how to get the connection string for your cloud DB.  So putting it all together, I have a simple google apps script to test the connection to my DB as follows:

```
function connect() {
    const dbUrl='jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.us-sanjose-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=g814b8501162211_userdata_high.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=adb.us-sanjose-1.oraclecloud.com, OU=Oracle ADB SANJOSE, O=Oracle Corporation, L=Redwood City, ST=California, C=US")))'    
    const conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, 'username', 'password');
}
```

However, this code fails on line 3 with an error message of

```
Exception: Invalid argument: url
```

I've searched and searched and can't find any example of making this connection.  I'll appreciate any help or guidance--even if it not a complete solution.

Comment: Please take a look to [`[jdbc] [google-apps-script] is:question is:answered`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjdbc%5D+%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+is%3Aquestion+is%3Aanswered&searchOn=3). There are already 183 answered questions.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Rubén.  I've looked over them all and none are addressing connecting to an Oracle Cloud DB; only one talks about connecting to Oracle (not cloud) and it is, as yet, unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Please enable 1-way TLS on the Autonomous Database and try it. You should see connect string with port# 1521

Here is a blog

https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/post/connecting-your-autonomous-database-has-never-been-easier

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Autonomous database has mutualTLS enabled by default. You can use either mTLS or enable TLS. Please refer to [quickstart with ADB](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/getting-started-using-jdbc.html) for more information. Also, you can look at the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNhGMWGqmLo&list=PLPIzp-E1msrZ8SDc5O5PpRTb12bOaBp8O&index=2).

Comment: Thanks for this.  It seems that the issue lies with google apps script as the code breaks when using the JDBC url required for making the TLS connection.  As yet, Ilave not found a way to properly form the mTLS connection string

Comment: The connection string is present in the wallet zip file that you download for your Autonomous database. All you need is the use the TNS alias in your connection string. jdbc:oracle:thin:@<yourdatabasename>_medium?TNS_ADMIN=<location-for-wallets-zip>

Comment: Thanks Nirmala, the problem is that in Google Apps Script, I don't think it's possible to reach out to the file system, so providing the path to the wallet is a non-starter.  That is what is so attractive about a TLS connection (rather than mTLS), no reference to the filesystem is needed

Comment: For a TLS connection, you can get the URL from the "DB Connection" tab from the console, choose TLS in the dropdown, and copy the connection URL to use in your code. You need to enable TLS before this. Check out the QuickStart with ADB (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/getting-started-using-jdbc.html)

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours and hours, I'm convinced that as of December 2022, it is not possible to connect from Google Apps Script to Oracle Autonomous Database (AKA Oracle Cloud Database) using the JDBC connection.

I did find a way to make the connection.  By default, Oracle Autonomous Databases have Oracle REST Data Service (ORDS) enabled.  This allows you to execute an arbitrary SQL statement by making a REST API call.  You need to know the endpoint for your autonomous DB which is available from "Manage Users" page of the Oracle Cloud Console.

[image]

Notice that the endpoint includes the username.  You will need to change the last 4 characters of the URL from "sdw/" to "/sql".  With that URL you are ready to connect from google apps script with the following sample code.

```
const oracle_url = "https://gXXXXXXXXXX211-junk.adb.us-sanjose-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/admin/_/sql" 
const username="ADMIN"
const password="P455W0RD"

function select_test(){
  const sql="select * from data.junk order by id"
  const result=oracle_sql(username,password, sql)
  console.log(result.items[0].resultSet.items)
}

function insert_test(){
  const sql="insert into data.junk values(2,'Sony Betamax')"
  const result=oracle_sql(username,password, sql)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
}

function oracle_sql(username, password, sql) {
    const options = {
      muteHttpExceptions:true,
      method:"post",
      payload:sql,
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/sql',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(`${username}:${password}`)
      }
    }
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(oracle_url, options)
    return JSON.parse(response.getContentText())    
}
```

The function named "insert_test" will add a record to a table (given the correct insert statement" and "select_test" will fetch values from the database.